# Empty header row is being added while using header slot in v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Empty row is being added while using header slot in v-data-table from vuetify2

Here's the codepen: 
https://codepen.io/satishvarada/pen/rNBjMjE?editors=1010

```
Vue.component('pivot-table',{
        data:()=>({
          pivotData:[["2018",1470,1436,1445,0],["2019",1953,1824,0,0]],
          pivotHeaders:[[{"value":"Month","colspan":1},{"value":"JAN","colspan":2},{"value":"FEB","colspan":2}],[{"value":"Year","colspan":1},{"value":"Count1","colspan":1},{"value":"Count2","colspan":1},{"value":"Count1","colspan":1},{"value":"Count2","colspan":1}]],
        }),

template:
`<v-data-table disable-sort disable-filtering :headers="pivotHeaders" :items="pivotData">
  <template v-slot:header="{ props: { headers } }"><thead class="v-data-table-header">
    <tr v-for="header in headers" style="background-color:yellow;"> 
     <th v-for="head in header" :colspan="head.colspan">{{head.value}}</th>
    </tr></thead>
   </template>
  <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item_row in items"><template v-for="item in item_row">
        <td>{{ item }}</td></template>
      </tr></tbody></template></v-data-table>`
})
```

Unexpected row is added below the header. The number of cells in this empty row is as same the number of rows present in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is related to you data structure since `v-data-table` accepts arrays of objects as props not an array of arrays, but your use case could be achieved using `v-simple-table` component in as follows :

```html
<v-simple-table>
  <thead>
    <tr v-for="header in pivotHeaders" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <th v-for="head in header" :colspan="head.colspan">{{head.value}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item_row in pivotData">
      <td v-for="item in item_row">{{ item }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</v-simple-table>
```

Comment: Good one. But v-simple-table doesn't possess pagination feature it seems.